# How to find higher yield investments if I'm 20+ years from retirement?

Tags: investment-strategies, retirement-plan, hedge-funds, high-yield

I am 37 and don't plan on using any of this money until I'm at least 50. Currently I'm using RobinHood and have mimicked Warren Buffet's top stock picks.

I'm currently looking into

- hedge funds
- day-trade managed accounts

What are some higher yield long term investment I can use and what is a realistic average return?

-- EDIT --

I'm not sure what the downvotes are for, what do I need to add to make sure this question is taken seriously? Thanks for the comments.

Comment: Also: we do not really do recommendations here - they are opinionated, and likely get outdated very fast.

Comment: Well, you're looking in to hedge funds? What about hedge funds? Linvesting like a hedge fund? Investing with a hedge fund? Investing in a hedge fund? I don't even k ow what a day trade managed account is? Are you saying youd like to start day trading?  Apparently 'buy tesla stock' was great advice in March even though it looked like a fundamentally bad idea, and looks like a fundamentally terrible idea now.

Answer (score 4):

You can use one of the many screeners at FINVIZ to find higher yield investments.

Note that:

- Yield is not indicative of return
- When it comes to high yield, yield and safety tend to be inversely related.

Comment: Right, the 'how to find' part is relatively easy -- lots of places let you slice and dice data however you choose. But, all the higher yields come with higher risk and being good enough to know when to buy and sell them requires a lot of knowledge and luck. OP has a lot of reading ahead of them. If it were easy to do, everyone would be doing it.

Comment: The OP might also misguidedly believe that yield is income, a fallacy promoted across the internet, hence his desire for high yield recommendations.